# Find Kernel of map $f:K[X,Y] \rightarrow K[T]$ defined by $f(X) = T^2, f(Y) = T^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $\ker f = (X^3-Y^2)$, but I don't know the reasons. I would like to see the steps to get solution.

Thanks in advance

Emanuele

Comment: Thanks, It's my first question.

Comment: Thanks, It's my first question. 
I'm studying commutative algebra sull'Atiyah. I have this exercise. $ K $ is a field and $ X, Y, T $ indeterminate. Let $ A = K [T ^ 2, T ^ 3] \subset  K [T] $. Prove that $ A \sim K [X, Y] / (X ^ 3-Y ^ 2) $.

The only thing I know is that if I can prove that $ Kerf = (X ^ 3-Y^ 2) $ I get the thesis. But I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $p(X,Y)=\sum\limits_{i,j}p_{i,j}X^iY^j \in \ker f$, then $f(p) = 0$. Applying $f$, we see that $f(p) = \sum\limits_{i,j}p_{i,j}T^{2i+3j}=0$. Now combine summands with equal powers of $T$ and remember that a polynomial equals zero iff all its coefficients are zero.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to solve, (with $p_(i,j)$ you mean coefficients, right?)

Comment: @emanuele Yes, the coefficients of $p(X,Y) \in k[X,Y]$.

Comment: @lisyarus we don't know what will be $p_{i,j}$, then how can we combine summands withequal powers of T ?

Comment: @mathiu_lady $p_{i,j}$ are just coefficients from field $k$. For example, to get $T^0$ we need $2i+3j=0$, Since $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$, this can happen only if $i=j=0$. Now, it is impossible to get $T^1$. For $T^2$, the only way is to have $i=1, j=0$, and so on. You will get $f(p) = p_{0,0} T^0 + p_{1,0} T^2 + p_{0,1} T^3 + p_{2,0} T^4 + p_{1,1} T^5 + (p_{3,0}+p_{0,2}) T^6 + \dots$.